# Need correct CSS to change active state of an html button?

Tags: html, css

I'm just jumping into CSS and would like to know how add css override format for the below button that I've pasted from the html output.

```
<li id="menu-item-59" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current_page_parent menu-item-59"><a href="http://some-website-blog.com/">Blog</a></li>
```

I need to change the active color state of the item. I've tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
body.bbPress #nav li.menu-item-59 a, body.bbPress #nav li.menu-item-59 a:active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Is the `.bbPress #nav` unnecessary? I've pasted that in from some other site.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by the "active" state? It might not mean what you think.

Comment: The selected state. Is that correct terminology?

Comment: If you mean that you want the lik to be colored a certain way when you are on the page it points to, then "current" would be better. Usually you'd add a special class to the link for that purpose. `:active` is for styling the link while you are clicking on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know if the `.bbPress #nav` is unnecessary we need to see more of the page.

You can try to use the `!important` on the CSS rule, but it's not recommended.

Something like this:

```
background-color: red !important;
```

Answer (score 1):

keep in mind that IDs are unique, so you can simply do this in order to simply target this specific element and nothing else:

```
#menu-item-59 a, #menu-item-59 a:active {
background-color: red;
}
```